# MySQL “Sending data” Very Slow

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with 200k+ records at the moment, which I am trying to do a COUNT(*) search. The search seems to be very quick until it gets to the Sending data phase.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `evento_inscricao_participante_ingresso` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_participante` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_carrinho` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_cortesia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`codigo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`checkin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`criado_em` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`modificado_em` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`criado_por` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`modificado_por` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`deletado` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
`deletado_por` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`deletado_em` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `codigo_UNIQUE` (`codigo`),
KEY `fk_evento_inscricao_participante_ingresso_evento_inscricao__idx` (`id_participante`),
KEY `fk_evento_inscricao_participante_ingresso_evento_inscricao__idx1` (`id_carrinho`),
KEY `fk_evento_inscricao_participante_ingresso_evento_cortesia1_idx` (`id_cortesia`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_evento_inscricao_participante_ingresso_evento_inscricao_ca1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_carrinho`) REFERENCES `evento_inscricao_carrinho` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL,
CONSTRAINT `fk_evento_inscricao_participante_ingresso_evento_inscricao_pa1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_participante`) REFERENCES `evento_inscricao_participante` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=175477 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM evento_inscricao_participante_ingresso t 
            LEFT JOIN evento_inscricao_carrinho c ON (c.id = t.id_carrinho) 
            LEFT JOIN evento_inscricao_participante p ON (p.id = t.id_participante) 
            LEFT JOIN evento_ingresso i ON (i.id = c.id_ingresso) 
            LEFT JOIN evento_inscricao ins ON (ins.id = c.id_inscricao) 
            LEFT JOIN evento_cortesia cortesia ON (t.id_cortesia = cortesia.id) 
            WHERE (i.id_evento = 894 
            AND i.id = 3255 AND ins.id_status = 1) 
            OR (cortesia.id_evento = 894 
            AND cortesia.id_ingresso = 3255 AND t.id_cortesia IS NOT NULL)
```

**Profile**

```
starting    0.000104
checking permissions    0.000004
checking permissions    0.000002
checking permissions    0.000002
checking permissions    0.000001
checking permissions    0.000002
checking permissions    0.000004
Opening tables  0.000048
System lock 0.000010
init    0.000029
optimizing  0.000016
statistics  0.000035
preparing   0.000020
executing   0.000004
Sending data    18.216500
end 0.000010
query end   0.000004
closing tables  0.000013
freeing items   0.000106
logging slow query  0.000004
cleaning up 0.000004
```

**Explain**

```
1   SIMPLE  t   ALL fk_evento_inscricao_participante_ingresso_evento_cortesia1_idx  NULL    NULL    NULL    205120  NULL
1   SIMPLE  c   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   ingresso_main.t.id_carrinho 1   NULL
1   SIMPLE  p   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   ingresso_main.t.id_participante 1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  i   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   ingresso_main.c.id_ingresso 1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  ins eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   ingresso_main.c.id_inscricao    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  cortesia    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   ingresso_main.t.id_cortesia 1   Using where
```

So what I don't understand why spend to much time if i already created index. When i deleted older records, the time improvement a 50%. I tested in production(Amazon RDS/m3.medium/5.6.35) and localhost(MySQL 5.6.35)

**Indexes for all tables used in join:**

```
evento_inscricao_carrinho   0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   76098   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
evento_inscricao_carrinho   1   FK_incricao_carrinho_x_evento_ingresso  1   id_ingresso A   76098   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao_carrinho   1   FK_incricao_carrinho_x_usuario  1   id_usuario  A   76098   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao_carrinho   1   FK_evento_inscricao_carrinho_x_evento_inscricao 1   id_inscricao    A   76098   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao_carrinho   1   fk_evento_inscricao_carrinho_evento_codigo_desconto1_idx    1   id_codigo_desconto  A   76098   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao_carrinho   1   fk_evento_inscricao_carrinho_evento_convite_envio1_idx  1   id_convite_restrito A   76098   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       

evento_inscricao_participante   0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   69614   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
evento_inscricao_participante   1   fk_evento_inscricao_participante_evento_inscricao1_idx  1   id_inscricao    A   69614   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao_participante   1   fk_evento_inscricao_participante_evento_inscricao_carrinho1_idx 1   id_carrinho A   69614   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       


evento_ingresso 0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   4021    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
evento_ingresso 1   FK_evento_ingresso_x_inquilino  1   id_inquilino    A   670 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_ingresso 1   FK_evento_ingresso_x_evento 1   id_evento   A   4021    NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_ingresso 1   fk_evento_ingresso_evento_ingresso1_idx 1   id_ingresso_lote    A   6   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       

evento_inscricao    0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   90011   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
evento_inscricao    1   FK_evento_incricao_x_tipo_pagamento 1   id_pagamento_tipo   A   90011   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao    1   FK_evento_inscricao_x_evento    1   id_evento   A   90011   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao    1   FK_evento_inscricao_x_usuario   1   id_usuario  A   90011   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao    1   fk_evento_inscricao_evento_inscricao_status1_idx    1   id_status   A   90011   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao    1   fk_evento_inscricao_evento_recorrencia1_idx 1   id_recorrencia  A   90011   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_inscricao    1   fk_evento_inscricao_terminal1_idx   1   id_terminal A   90011   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       

evento_cortesia 0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   778 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
evento_cortesia 1   FK_evento_apoio_x_evento    1   id_evento   A   129 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_cortesia 1   fk_evento_cortesia_evento_recorrencia1_idx  1   id_recorrencia  A   1   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_cortesia 1   fk_evento_cortesia_evento_ingresso1_idx 1   id_ingresso A   259 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
evento_cortesia 1   fk_evento_cortesia_terminal1_idx    1   id_terminal A   21  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
```

Comment: can you provide us the show index from all the tables which you mentioned in the joins and main table ?

Comment: Please don't use off-site resources like pastebin for your questions. The purpose here is to have others learn from your experience, and if you bury important information off site you defeat that.

Comment: Sorry, i will edit my post with the indexes.

Comment: What i see since i am active on stack is that the best way to get the best help is to give all the needed information on stack do not use photo or whatever only important information. The community want that ppl give energy in his question

Comment: "sending data" is notoriously useless.  Hence, I find Profiling useless.  The `WHERE` clause is scattered across 6 tables -- Ouch. And it has an `OR`.  The only solution I can think of is to restructure the schema.  But I don't understand Portuguese, so I don't have a feel for the schema.

Answer (score 2):

The indices you've created are helping with the JOINs, but evaluating most of the `WHERE` conditions is still requiring MySQL to iterate over most of the 200k rows in the table to calculate the `COUNT()`. This takes time.

It's unlikely that this query can be optimized to be much faster without significant changes to the structure of your database.

Comment: what did you mean about "significant changes" ? create another table?

Comment: Could you explain what for changes ? @duskwuff I want to improve myself on this subject. If you can give us more information. I know that if the query has to lookup 20 % > of the table is faster the not use index in the query